# scale_fill_discrete values not being used

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm new to ggplot2, and I'm currently using it to plot several lines on a graph of distance (x) against mortality rate (y) over several years. I can get the lines to display, but I'm trying to sort out the legend, which should display which colour represents which year. I've read many things about this but I can't seem to get the scale_fill_discrete command to change my legend accordingly. Here's my current code:

```
g <- ggplot(filtered, aes(x=filtered$distance)) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = filtered$RelativeDeaths.2014, color = "v"),size = 0.5) +  # basic graphical object
  geom_line(linetype = "solid", aes(y=filtered$RelativeDeaths.2014,color = "v")) +
  geom_point(aes(y = filtered$RelativeDeaths.2015,color = "x"),size = 0.5) +# first layer
  geom_line(linetype = "solid", aes(y=filtered$RelativeDeaths.2015,color = "x")) +
  geom_point(aes(y = filtered$RelativeDeaths.2016,color = "y"),size = 0.5) +
  geom_line(linetype = "solid", aes(y=filtered$RelativeDeaths.2016,color = "y")) +
  geom_point(aes(y = filtered$RelativeDeaths.2017,color = "z"),size = 0.5) +
  geom_line(linetype = "solid", aes(y=filtered$RelativeDeaths.2017,color = "z")) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c(v="red",x="blue",y="green",z="yellow"))+
        scale_fill_discrete(name = "Year", labels = c("2014", "2015", "2016","2017"))



g <- g + ylab("Relative Mortality Rates 2014 - 2017") + xlab("Distance To Canal") 

g
```

And heres a look at my filtered data frame with the relevant columns:

```
dput(head(filtered[cols], 20))
structure(list(distance = c(30.4493274665705, 32.690767619627, 
50.423978523969, 105.398975038182, 149.880076901593, 154.928665795813, 
178.886949742468, 197.37523391094, 200.977994666642, 201.635948013352, 
243.023605110627, 263.223206608342, 276.989624513379, 286.759943907289, 
291.861599835967, 292.419257603377, 292.463221848888, 309.224411286688, 
310.957457758306, 324.537645878657), RelativeDeaths.2014 = c(-5, 
-6, -5, -2, -4, -5, -2, -6, 5, -7, 2, -3, -5, -6, 6, -3, -4, 
-3, -5, -2), RelativeDeaths.2015 = c(-5, -5, -6, -2, -6, -7, 
-4, -2, 3, -4, 1, -3, -4, -5, -4, -7, -1, -8, -4, -3), RelativeDeaths.2016 = c(-3, 
-6, -2, -5, -3, -3, 2, -1, 2, -2, 1, -2, 4, 3, 2, 1, -5, -6, 
-4, -3), RelativeDeaths.2017 = c(-4, -6, -9, -5, -6, 0, -5, -3, 
-2, -7, -2, -1, -3, -1, 2, -1, -4, -4, -7, -5)), row.names = c(561L, 
562L, 599L, 606L, 563L, 709L, 594L, 603L, 598L, 612L, 572L, 597L, 
604L, 595L, 602L, 716L, 609L, 708L, 616L, 711L), class = "data.frame")
```

However, the values displayed in the legend are the variables I use for colour, x,x,y,z. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Get rid of `filtered$` everywhere but in `ggplot(filtered, etc)`.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(filtered)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(filtered, 20))`.

Comment: The output with both of those commands is far too big to post, I'm afraid.

Comment: You only have 5 variables that matter, `distance` and `RelativeDeaths.2014` to `RelativeDeaths.2017`. If you post just those it should become (much) smaller. Is there a `colour` variable? Also, the problem seems to be a data format one, you have your data in wide format when it should be in long format.

Comment: How would I do that as a command? Sorry, I'm a relative newbie to R. Also, no there is no ```colour``` variable in the dataframe.

Comment: First, `cols <- c("distance", "RelativeDeaths.2014", etc, "RelativeDeaths.2017")`. Then, `dput(head(filtered[cols], 20))`

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the main post accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Rui, above, you can drop all of the `filtered$` in your variable selections.

You should also be able to do away with `linetype=solid`, which is the default for `geom_line()`.

It may help to name the colors based on the year you're plotting (e.g. `"2014"` instead of "`x`" so that these names show up in the legend instead of the letters.

Finally, try splitting up the parameters in `scale_color_manual()`, using both `breaks` and `values`:

```
g <- ggplot(filtered) + 
  # 2014
  geom_point(aes(x = distance,
                 y = RelativeDeaths.2014, 
                 color = "2014"),
             size = 0.5) +  # basic graphical object
  geom_line(aes(x = distance,
                y = RelativeDeaths.2014,
                color = "2014")) +
  # 2015
  geom_point(aes(x = distance,
                 y = RelativeDeaths.2015,
                 color = "2015"),
             size = 0.5) +# first layer
  geom_line(aes(x = distance,
                y = RelativeDeaths.2015,
                color = "2015")) +
  # 2016
  geom_point(aes(x = distance,
                 y = RelativeDeaths.2016,
                 color = "2016"),
             size = 0.5) +
  geom_line(aes(x = distance,
                y = RelativeDeaths.2016,
                color = "2016")) +
  # 2017
  geom_point(aes(x = distance,
                 y = RelativeDeaths.2017,
                 color = "2017"),
             size = 0.5) +
  geom_line(aes(x = distance,
                y = RelativeDeaths.2017,
                color = "2017")) +
  scale_color_manual(breaks = c("2014",
                                "2015",
                                "2016",
                                "2017"),
                     values = c("red",
                                "blue",
                                "green",
                                "orange")) +
  ylab("Relative Mortality Rates 2014 - 2017") +
  xlab("Distance to Canal")

g
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution is much more elegant and gives me exactly what I wanted! Thanks again!

Comment: Glad it worked! I recommend you check out Rui's answer post for reshaping the data. That's a great way to make the plotting code much cleaner and more succinct.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is a data format problem. The data is in a wide format, when `ggplot` works better with data in long format. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format) for many ways of solving this issue.

I will use package `reshape2`, function `melt` to reshape the data. Then, the plotting code becomes very simple, with just one call to each of `geom_line` and `geom_point`. And even the coloring code becomes simpler. A variable of the long format data set is the `colour` variable (ironically named `variable`).

```
library(ggplot2)

df_long <- reshape2::melt(filtered, id.vars = "distance")

ggplot(df_long, aes(distance, value, colour = variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(
    name = "Year", 
    labels = c("2014", "2015", "2016","2017"),
    values = c("red", "blue", "green", "yellow")) +
  ylab("Relative Mortality Rates 2014 - 2017") + 
  xlab("Distance To Canal")
```

[image]